# Sort Array Key and Value by another arrays value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two Arrays and need to sort one by the other.

The Array with the order has the categories as Value:

```
$order = array(
      0 => 12,
      1 => 14,
      2 => 15,
      3 => 17,
      4 => 20
      );
```

The Array i need to sort has unique ids as keys and the categorie as Value, and categories have duplicates:

```
$array = array(
     432 => 20,
     433 => 20,
     235 => 15,
     543 => 17,
     564 => 17,
     879 => 14,
     125 => 12,
     987 => 12,
     453 => 20
);
```

What i need is an Array with sorted ids as keys or values(preferred):

```
// sorted as keys
$sorted = array(
    125 => 12,
    987 => 12,
    879 => 14,
    235 => 15,
    543 => 17,
    564 => 17,
    432 => 20,
    433 => 20,
    453 => 20 
);


// or sorted as values
$sorted = array(
    0 => 125,
    1 => 987,
    2 => 879,
    3 => 235,
    4 => 543,
    5 => 564,
    6 => 432,
    7 => 433,
    8 => 453
);
```

Comment: Not clear question.

Answer (score 0):

First sort array key ascending order then do [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) based on `$order` array.

```
ksort($array);
uasort($array, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return (array_search($a, $order) < array_search($b, $order)) ? -1 : 1;
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you have:

```
$array = array(
 432 => 20,
 433 => 20,
 235 => 15,
 543 => 17,
 564 => 17,
 879 => 14,
 125 => 12,
 987 => 12,
 453 => 20
);
```

This need to be processed like this:

1. To get array sorted by key in ascending order: `$sorted = ksort($array);`
2. To get array sorted by key in descending order: `$sorted = krsort($array);`

Comment: The categorie ids from $order are not always sorted by value!

Comment: @lichtscheu i think i misunderstood your question.